# Drag & Drop File on input type file doesn't work any more ( Windows 10)

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, drag-and-drop, windows-10

I have upgraded my computer to Windows 10 and downloaded the latest Google Chrome : `Version 49.0.2623.87 m`

My application wasn't using any special scripts to enable drag and drop file upload. It was just using the default behaviour that when you drag a file over an `<input type="file" />` field it got selected as if you would click on it and select the file manually.

This behaviour doesn't work any more -> When I drop the file above the input field, the file gets opened / downloaded within the browser.

Has any1 encountered the same issue ? Is it fixable?

Comment: Are you using non-100% page zoom of Google Chrome, or using non-standard DPI setting of Windows?

Comment: Thank you - I haven't considered this being a possible issue but after changing my clients zoom back to 100% the drag & drop functionality works as intended